# Backup database - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need make a backup of my SQL Server database. When I try, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Read on "c:..." failed: 23(...)(Data error (cyclic redundancy error))

Now, I'm trying to run this command:

```
DBCC CheckDB ('MYDATABASE') WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

But I get this error

> Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
> Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.

What can I do? I just need make a backup.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You should be able to just right click the DB in SSMS go to Tasks -> Backup DB.

Comment: @Brad yes, i did.

Comment: @I try but I get this error:
Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.

Comment: Run the backup in SSMS in the query editor (`backup database xxx to disk = 'filename.bak'`) and then get all the error output. You should now be able to read what are the previous errors are that the message you are receiving now are referring to.

Comment: `cyclic redundancy` sounds like a serious problem with your actual C: drive. It may not help if the database itself is already damaged but could you try backing up to an external USB drive or to a network location?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I try to D: and I get this error: 
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Cannot open backup device 'D:\duplicados.bak'. Operating system error 3(O sistema não conseguiu localizar o caminho especificado.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: You won't be able to backup to a root, try creating a folder like `D:\Backups` and making sure the SQL Server service account has permissions to write there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand same error

Comment: The error is "The system cannot find the file specified" I don't know that we can help you with this. Are you sure you created a folder on D:\ called Backups and are you sure you gave the SQL Server service account write permissions to it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the Service Account used for the SQL Server Instance from Services.
Ensure the service account have enough permission for read/write at the exact location for Backup in Physical Disk.
Ensure the the user (the user you using to login in SQL Instance) have enough permission to perform backup.

Final option to recover the data from the database is create another database with same tables (blank) in different machine in different SQL instance, then Export all the database to new database using Management studio (Right click on the Database > task > Export Data)

Comment: Sorry but how can i verify if I have permission for read or write? I'm new in this area..

Comment: Check Security of the Directory (Right Click > Properties > Security Tab)

Comment: i only have this:

General   ---   Files;
FileGroups   ---   Options
Change Tracking   ---   Permissions
Extended Properties   ---   Query Store

In permissions, all are check! :D

Comment: "Check the Service account using for the SQL instance from Services (Administrative Tools > Services)", Ensure that service account having permission to read/write permission in your backup location (file read/write permission on physical disk over the OS), by default SQL Instance used 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK' for the service account to run which does not have permission all over your system drives to read/write, so check it well