# Remove one of the two Lines with repeated value - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did a query, and I get rows with a repeated field. Field lot Table Z. I want to make a query where i remove one of the two lines where the lot field is repeated.

> I tried this:

```
delete from tableZ where id=(select TOP 1 rt.id from tableZ rt WHERE lot=(select lot, count(id) as cnt from tableZ  group by lot having count(id)>1))
```

> And I got this error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

FOR EXAMPLE:

SELECT * FROM TABLE;

> RESULTS: 1 2 3 3 4 5

I want make one query to delete one of two repeated values.. After query.

> RESULTS: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Kendle I'm using SQL

Comment: SQL is general, and it's different for MySQL, MSSQL (sql-server), PostgreSQL, etc, you might add the tag for the DBMS you are actually using

Comment: Please give us the output of the command `select version();`

Comment: @Kendle: not all DBMS systems have that function, SQL-SERVER i.e. will return: `'version' is not a recognized built-in function name.`  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3308b7a7b71fd93243158334f509a69b )

Comment: @Luuk the question **was** tagged mySQL !

Comment: @Luuk 
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR)

Comment: @JoséMarquês: please tag your questions with `sql-server`, to make clear to everyone that you are using MS SQL SERVER

Comment: @Kendle: Sorry, did not notice, but saw another post from José about [SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71913385/backup-database-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. You are returning two columns to the right side of the expression (`a = b,c` and as you see it does not make sense). This is what your error message is telling you
2. The WHERE clause is using an equal, which means it expects only one value not a list of values... I see you use the TOP 1 to avoid it but there are better ways of doing it.

I'd use some windowing functions to obtain a clean list for the delete, something like this *should* work, I expect it to work on any SQL DB.

In order to see/understand what it does run the innermost query, you will then find plenty of resources about windowing functions out there on the internet

```
DELETE FROM tableZ 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM (
    SELECT
       id
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lot ORDER BY id ASC) as RowNum
      ,COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY lot) as LotCount
    FROM tableZ rt
    ) as x
    WHERE
      x.RowNum = 1
      AND x.LotCount > 1
)
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have window function on older versions. That's why I asked the version used.

Comment: I work almost exclusively with SQL Server, but so far I've never had issues with other DBs... I learn/check what's supported on other DBs on the fly... anyway til MySQL supports windowing functions from version 8, which was released on 19 April 2018... this wasn't expected as it's quite "recent"